# How do you perform sql queries in emacs-lisp scripts?

Tags: sql

I am building a database application to index org-mode files (http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2017/01/03/Find-stuff-in-org-mode-anywhere/). The first iteration used emacsql, which worked well for a proof of concept, but it builds a database that isn't easily compatible with other ways to interact with the database because it stores things as lisp-readable values. I would like to try using sql strings in the scripts more directly for CRUD operations on the database so that other scripts, e.g. in Python, or the shell could also interact with the database.

Is there another way to use sql inside of emacs-lisp scripts? In particular a library that would enable syntax like this where ? (or something like it) is a placeholder for values:

`(sql-execute "SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=?" t)`

That is apparently a more secure way (https://xkcd.com/327/) to do this than:

`(sql-execute (format "SELECT * FROM stocks WHERE symbol=%s" t))`

The command would return a list of results? It is not essential that it work on sqlite, eventually I will use a server like postgresql or mysql I think. I have found many sql-modes, repls, etc. but nothing that seems designed for working in scripts.

Comment: I don't know if there is.  I remember reading about this problem in some Lispbook.  The author used it as an example for a domain-specific-language using macros.  So, if you're going to implement this, I would go a step further and drop the string altogether.

Comment: That is basically what emacsql does. It transforms elisp code to sql and then runs it.  I have actually been going back and forth on sql vs. mongodb. it is trivial to convert a lisp data structure to a json query for mongo, but there are other challenges of interacting with mongo I have not overcome yet.

Comment: So, what I was suggesting is what you currently have... And the reason for the need of a string based API is, that you are able to use the same strings in a python script etc. ?

Comment: No I don't need strings at all. Most other wrappers. Have seen use them with placeholders though. Emacsql would be great if it wasnt storing lisp readable things so I could have other scripts also read and write to the db.

Comment: I think I have changed my mind on sql strings. It looks like making a complete dsl for sql would be very difficult, and never complete. sql strings on the other hand would support every feature that a particular db could do out of the box.